# How to zoom in with a mouse?

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm using MBP and external monitor, keyboard and mouse. I'd like to be able to zoom in the text in Safari. Safari keyboard shortcuts for zooming text are<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd>. I would like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+scrolling with the mouse. This works in Windows 7 for instance.

Currently, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+scrolling is zooming the entire screen, not text.

Can I zoom text in Safari using a mouse?

Answer (score 1):

- To zoom inside safari you can use 2 fingers pinching in the trackpad.
- 2 fingers tap will zoom so the text fits the safari window.
- Also a single finger double tap in the mighty mouse does the same trick.
  (not double click)

If you want even more ways to do stuff with your mouse I know about this software called [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com) that I used for quite some time and loved it.
There is also a similar software called [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net/).

Answer (score 0):

To turn off zooming of the screen go to the *Accessibility* preference pane ad uncheck the following option under the *Zoom* section:

> Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom:

This might release the functionality you wanted.

Unfortunately I cannot test this since I'm using a MBP without a mouse and so I can only use the trackpad pinch zoom (however, I would rarely do that over using the keyboard).

Comment: I unchecked it now and it doesn't zoom in Mac-style, but it doesn't zoom-in the text in Safari either.

Answer (score 0):

I found partial answer:
I'm using BetterTouchTool and using Ctrl+Left/Right mouse button I can zoom in/out text - couldn't find a way to do it via scrolling instead of mouse's buttons.